# Remove rows based on several combinations in multiple columns

Tags: r

In R, I need to remove rows with multiple combinations from 2 character columns.  I have searched for a solution, but most questions either deal with duplicates, or are only trying to remove 1 combination, not multiple combinations based on two columns.  Here is an example df:

```
Species   Harvest  Hunt.Type
Sheep       1         Gun
Goat        4         Bow
Turkey      3         Gun
Pig         2         Bow
Quail       6         Bow
```

Here, I would need to remove any row that has a mammal species with "Gun" in the Hunt.Type, and any row that has a bird species with a "Bow" Hunt.Type. So I would want to end up with this:

```
Species   Harvest  Hunt.Type
Goat        4         Bow
Turkey      3         Gun
Pig         2         Bow
```

My data frame is much larger than this with 13 species and many more columns and rows.

I tried to do this using extract on conditions in base r as well as dplyr but I could not figure it out because of the added complication of the multiple combinations of species.

I tried something like this in base r:

```
df[df$Species== c("Goat" , "Sheep", "Pig") & 
       df$Hunt.Type == "Gun",]
```

But for some reason that code omits some rows with those conditions, and keeps others.  for dplyr, I have not been able to get anything even close.

Comment: You say any mammal but you are specifying a list of species, does that mean that you don't have a variable indicating bird versus mammal?   You will want to change the first part of your statement to  `df$Species %in%  c("Goat" , "Sheep", "Pig")` since you don't expect the species to be vector.

Comment: That is my problem, I only need to remove the row when "Bow" occurs with a bird species and "Gun" with a mammal. I was thinking maybe create a vector of all the bird species and use that as a condition to help weed out the target rows. So in this case I would do something like: `bird.keywords <- c("Turkey", "Quail")` and likewise for mammals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest to create a vector of all birds or mammals (whichever is shorter) and then filter. We need only one of them since the other half are just their complements. So assuming if a `Species` is not bird then it's a mammal and vice versa.

So for this example, we can do

```
bird.keywords <- c("Turkey", "Quail")
df[!with(df, (Species %in% bird.keywords & Hunt.Type == "Bow") | 
             (!Species %in% bird.keywords) & Hunt.Type == "Gun"),]


#  Species Harvest Hunt.Type
#2    Goat       4       Bow
#3  Turkey       3       Gun
#4     Pig       2       Bow
```